# mapping of JSON keys with leading "@" with restkit

Tags: ios, json, restkit-0.20

I am working with rest kit 0.20.3 for some project now without issues.
Right now I am facing the problem that the JSON keys have leading "@" which causes Restkit to crash while mapping the data.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "city": {
        "@name": "Charles Redirection City",
        "@nameUrl": "Charles Redirection City",
        "lat": "52.5238",
        "long": "13.4119",
        "zipCode": "666"
    },
    "categories": {
        "@count": "20037",
        "category": [
            {
                "@count": "2326",
                "@hasChildren": "true",
                "id": "15777",
                "name": "Sticky-Categorie"
            }
        ]
    },
    "additional": {
        "dataKey": [
            {
                "@key": "log-start",
                "$": "home"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

While mapping the app crashes with

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFDictionary 0x95b5360> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hasChildren.'
```

as it tries to call hasChildren on the dictionary. My mapping look like this:

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id"                 :   @"categoryId",
                                              @"name"               :   @"name",
                                              @"@hasChildren"       :   @"doesHaveChildren",
                                              @"@count"             :   @"numbersOfJobs",
                                              @"trackingName"       :   @"trackingString"
                                              }];
```

I already tried to apply my own mapping which unfortunately didn't work. 
Is a leading @ not supported in RestKit? I already parsed the JSON with NSJSONSerialization which worked fine but I really love the mapping feature of RestKit and would like to avoid writing my own mapping :)

Comment: hold on, I have the solution, I'm digging it out for you... bear with me. I'm serious.

Comment: There are a few potential solutions, as you see below. There is no official solution. You may find this useful: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/1384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` is used in [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html):

> Collection operators are specialized key paths that are passed as the parameter to the `valueForKeyPath:` method. The operator is specified by a string preceded by an at sign (`@`).

I don't know of a way to tell `NSDictionary` to ignore it. You could remove the `@` from your JSON, either on the server end, or after you receive it but before you hand it to RestKit's mapper.

Comment: You ignore it by calling objectForKey: instead of valueForKeyPath:. That's why valueForKeyPath: which many people use blindly without knowing what it does will be dangerous.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think the OP was trying to fix the issue without modifying RestKit.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is that e.g. re-building the dictionary with new keys, which won't hold any `@` character. that is how you can *read* values in an `NSDictionary` which has `@` characters in keys.

I just replace the `@` in keys with `_` on the top level here for the new dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *_dictionary; // your original dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *_validatedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[_dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *_validKey = [key stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"_"];
    [_validatedDictionary setObject:obj forKey:_validKey];
}];
```

*NOTE: that is just a concept idea which works on the top-level only in my code, you may use it to create a recursive algorithm to replace deeper levels.*

Comment: Your code replaces all occurrences of `@`, not just when `@` is first. Also, you might want your code to check for or handle the case in which there's already a key with that name.

Comment: of couse it replaces! how else could you deal with those keys? the OP needs to rebuild the dictionary without having `@` in keys, and then the dictionary becomes useful in an iOS app.

Comment: Keys like `one@two` don't need to be replaced, and if there is a key like `onetwo` also, your code will overwrite it.

Comment: as you see the substitue character is `_`, but where I'm sitting at I have no information about back-end and the possible types of keys. so, please stop losing in details here, because my answer clearly says that is a concept idea only, how the OP can read the values for those keys it is up to the OP, and eventually you have not presented any idea, but quoting Apple. sometimes this issue has to be solved inside the application without blaming the external services, and that is quite clever idea on iOS-level.

Comment: You can read keys with leading @ without problems if you use objectForKey. The problem is with RestKit that uses valueForKey (KVC). He can replace all keys in the JSON without the needing to iterate through it, the keys are accessible directly. Moreover, since the JSON come as a string, before being encoded in a dictionary/array, I think that it would be better to replace the occurrences there, and only then encoding the JSON. Assuming that RestKit let you do this, I don't know if it lets you manipulating the received data before mapping it, and assuming that the OP wants to change the keys

Answer (score 0):

If you can't replace the keys removing the @, there is another solution to test for.
It could be a little bit drastic, but you can try to subclass NSDictionary to replace the implementation of the `-(id)valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath` method.

I say that it is drastic because subclassing a class cluster (like `NSDictionary` is never easy, and you will have to do many tests to be sure that RestKit doesn't complain about this.

Moreover, this won't work if RestKit copies the dictionary in a "custom" manner (for example constructing from zero a brand new NSDictionary instead of using copy on our custom subclass).

The goal is to have a subclass that implements a method like this

```
-(id)valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    if ([[keyPath substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"@"])
    {
        return [_subDictionary objectForKey:keyPath];   // if the first character is @, return the result of objectForKey
    } else {
        return [_subDictionary valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    }

}
```

You can change the method to return the value of `objectForKey`, instead of the value of `valueForKeyPath` only in some situations (if the key is "@hasChildren" for example).

This will give you this result:

```
self.aDictionary = [[FLDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"pluto"] forKeys:@[@"@pippo"]];
NSLog(@"Value is %@", [self valueForKeyPath:@"aDictionary.@pippo"]);


NSLog result: 2014-06-18 19:24:34.605 Swift123[25663:454958] Value is pluto
```

However, now comes the difficult part. To subclass NSDictionary, a class cluster, you'll have to override these methods:

```
-(instancetype)initWithObjects:(const id [])objects forKeys:(const id<NSCopying> [])keys count:(NSUInteger)cnt;
-(NSUInteger)count;
-(id)objectForKey:(id)aKey;
-(NSEnumerator *)keyEnumerator;
```

Override means that you should implement your own storage for the new created dictionary. To avoid this, I created an instance variable with an underlying NSDictionary.
I'll post the complete code at the end of the post.

Another thing to take note: it's a convention to copy NSDictionaries.
This would cause your custom class to be turned in a standard NSDictionary at the first copy.
For this reason, you have even to subclass the `copyWithZone:` method.

Here a full working example:

```
//
//  FLDictionary.m
//  Swift123
//
//  Created by Lombardo on 18/06/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lombardo. All rights reserved.
//
```

## import "FLDictionary.h"

```
@interface FLDictionary ()

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSDictionary *subDictionary;

@end

@implementation FLDictionary


-(instancetype)initWithObjects:(const id [])objects forKeys:(const id<NSCopying> [])keys count:(NSUInteger)cnt
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _subDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys count:cnt];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSUInteger)count
{
    return [_subDictionary count];
}

-(id)objectForKey:(id)aKey
{
    return [_subDictionary objectForKey:aKey];
}

-(NSEnumerator *)keyEnumerator
{
    return [_subDictionary keyEnumerator];
}

-(id)valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    if ([[keyPath substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"@"])
    {
        return [_subDictionary objectForKey:keyPath];
    } else {
        return [_subDictionary valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    }

}



-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    id objects[ [_subDictionary count] ];
    id keys[ [_subDictionary count] ];

    int i = 0;
    for (id item in [_subDictionary allValues])
    {
        objects[i++] = item;
    }

    i = 0;
    for (id item in [_subDictionary allKeys])
    {
        keys[i++] = item;
    }

    FLDictionary *dict = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys count:[_subDictionary count]];
    return dict;

}

@end
```

Comment: I would argue with your very first sentence, because the OP can replace it, and can remove the leading `@` character from keys in iOS.

Comment: When I see "if you can't replace" the meaning is "if you don't want to replace" (for other external reason). Change the structure of the JSON is the first, "banal", possible answer,

Comment: I strongly could argue about how banal making a **valid** dictionary and keeping the collection operator free for letting it do its own purpose – your solution simply ruins all changes to use the KVC properly. you just sacrifise more than you really gain after and you believe that it is a 'smart' idea...... I'll name it as is, that is a quite stupid advice in long term of the application lifetime.

Comment: It doesn't break anything if you do it in the right way (changing the behavior only for some keys or, even better, create your own escape sequence, for example double @@. The lacks of an escape sequence is clearly a bug or a forgetfulness of Apple). I never sayd that yours is a stupid advice and I invite you to moderate your tones. When I said "banal", the mean was "if the problem is in the input json, I think that the OP had evaluated the possibility to change it, there is no difficult in doing it. If he is asking something here, it's maybe because the first answer is not the good one"

Comment: I did not think you said that mine would be stupid. I clearly said that phrase about your idea only (even if it can be technically brilliant). that is just a terrible pattern. saying something like _"It doesn't break anything if you do it in the right way"_ is far from a good enough solution. that is my opinion here, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the contributions. After wiggling around for some hours I followed @holey and @LombaX advice to replace the result. A simply but brilliant approach!

I ended up in replacing the received JSON once it available by simply calling a replace i.e.

```
NSString *responseStringer = operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString;
responseStringer = [responseStringer stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"@" withString:@"\""];
NSData *data = [responseStringer dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError* error;
id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:data MIMEType:@"application/json" error:&error];
```

passing the result (parsedData) again to RestKit for mapping:

```
NSDictionary *mappingsDictionary = @{ @"jobCategories.category": MY_RKObjectMapping_MAPPING_OBJECT };
RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];
NSError *mappingError = nil;
BOOL isMapped = [mapper execute:&mappingError];
if (isMapped && !mappingError) { ... }
```

Thank you so much for your help and pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: Arg... Forgot to thank @Aaron Brager (first one to contribute the replacement tip). Thanks mate!